# Please explain code block "for( auto &it : iostr )"

Tags: c++, auto

I have recently come across a sample code that I have been studying in advance for future use, and trying to convert it to code that I can understand using terms I have previously studied. However, I have failed to produce a code that somehow replicates what `for( auto &it : iostr )` does. Can someone explain what this does?

Comment: [Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: @songyuanyao I find it puzzling that this question doesn't seem to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

That's a [**range-based `for`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), introduced in C++11.

In your example with something called `iostr` as the expression, it loops over all items in `iostr`, as specified by the span `begin(iostr)` to `end(iostr)`.

Still in your example, with `auto &it` as the loop variable, for each item, `it` (which name is probably a misnomer!) is bound to that item, and the loop body is executed with that binding. It would be better to rename `it` to `item`. Or perhaps `ch`, or whatever it is that `iostr` contains.

Answer (score 0):

**This loops over elements in `iostr`.**

Per [this excellent reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (which you should get into the habit of using), this construct is currently exactly equivalent to:

```
{
   auto && __range = iostr; 
   for (auto __begin = std::begin(__range), __end = std::end(__range);
           __begin != __end;
           ++__begin) { 
      auto& it = *__begin; 
      // (your loop body here)
   } 
}
```

Or, more simply in this case:

```
for (auto __begin = std::begin(iostr), __end = std::end(iostr);
           __begin != __end;
           ++__begin) { 
      auto& it = *__begin; 
   // (your loop body here)
}
```

Since C++17, there is a slight modification to how `__begin` and `__end` are declared, to allow for them being of different types (as long as they can be compared using `!=`), but you may read all about that in the documentation.